# Django, custom 404/500 for when i return status_code 404 or 500

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I wrote the custom 404/500 pages for my Django applications, and they work ok, except when I explicitly return response with status code 500 or 404 from my views.

In the latter case I get whatever content I return in the response. I understand that I can render my 404 and 500 templates in those responses, but is there a way to automatically use those 404/500 pages?

To illustrate my question:

When a request is sent to "http://my.host/pattern_not_matching_anything", i get my 404.html page just fine.

But, when an invalid request is received at http://my.host/valid_pattern/invalid_parameter", that is, my view gets called, I look for the parameter in the DB and don't find it, and thus I return the appropriate response:

```
return HttpResponse("not found", status_code=404)
```

The HTML page returned contains only "not found", while I expected it to render the full 404 template that I customized.

Comment: An alternative way would be to return a call to one of the built-in error views; e.g [`return django.views.defaults.server_error(request)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/views/#django.views.defaults.server_error).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of returning a response with `status_code=404`, you should raise a `Http404` exception:

```
from django.http import 

def my_view(request, slug):
    try:
        obj = MyModel.object.get(slug=slug)
    except MyModel.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404

    ...
```

This is a common pattern in Django, so you can use the `get_object_or_404` shortcut instead.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def my_view(request, slug):
    obj = get_object_or_404(MyModel, slug=slug)
    ...
```

The status code 500 is when something has gone wrong with your server. You shouldn't deliberately return a response with status code 500.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that we want to catch certain errors and do different things with them before we return 500 to the user, it seems rather strange to just reraise exceptions after we have done something about them, thus we just return the error response.

Comment: If your application catches an exception, then I don't think you should be returning status code 500 because there's probably a better, more specific error code. If you really want to return status code 500, then re-raise the exception and Django will catch it and render your 500 template.

Comment: @Ibolit please don't feel strange re-raising an exception, it's fully supported in python and has it's valid use cases. Specifically in [Django's exception middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/middleware/#exception-handling) handles these special exceptions for you, and you can [customize the views it renders](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views).